# Android Application without User Interaction - Capture Photo, Call, Send MMS Automatically

Tags: android, camera, call, mms

I need to create an android application that waits for an input from a microcontroller connected through USB interface.  Once the microcontroller sends an input, the Android phone should take a photo, save it in SD card, call a specific contact in the phone book, then send the captured photo via MMS.  This is like a doorbell Android application.  Is it possible? If yes, please help me. thanks.

Comment: Possible, yes, but what are you asking? Which microcontroller to use? How to get the signal from USB? The taking a picture and sending an MMS part is stuff you can get from the android developers' website.

Answer (score 0):

The [USB Host and Accessory documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/usb/index.html) will be very helpful here. It depends on whether the microcontroller acts as the USB host or the Android device does. You may have to do some implementation work in C or C++ as well.